# INSER TO EXCEL XLSX?

Tags: sql-server, insert, xls, xlsx

Пытаюсь сохранить выгрузку в xlsx и sql отказывается сохранять, если инсертить в xls, то сохраняет, если в xlsx то нет. В чем подвох понять не могу. Заранее спасибо)

Делаю так:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(
   'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
   'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\file.xlsx;HDR=YES', 
   'select * FROM [Sheet1$]')
SELECT * FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Проверьте что версия AccessDatabaseEngine соответствует версии вашего SQL Server. (x32, x64)

2) Проверьте что установленный провайдер находится в списке

```
EXEC sp_enum_oledb_providers
```

3) Перед чтением / записью в xlsx, выполняйте скрипт:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO

EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO
```

4) Выполните свой скрипт.

PS. + Попробуйте явно указать столбцы для чтения / записи.

Comment: Нет, я перепутал, сохранение в файле не происходит. Указал столбцы, сделал sp_conf, файл создаю xp_cmdshell, пытаюсь туда сохранить результат запроса, файл создается, но пустой.

Comment: @noanother прав то хватает на sp_configure? По чек листу вы все сделали?

Comment: Да, история какая, идет сначала sp_configure, потом xp_cmdshell потом OPENROWSET, так вот файл то создается после выполнения, но пустой, значит прав хватает..

Comment: Вы не пробовали писать в существующий файл. Мб проблема с доступом к файлу.

Comment: К сожалению файл нужно создавать всегда перед наполнением, там для каждого файла будет своя выборка по условию..Просто странно, создать файл есть права, а наполнить нет...

Comment: Я вам не предлагаю менять ваш алгоритм, вы попробуйте в существующий файл писать. Просто для проверки.

Comment: Да непонятно, доступ дал специально еще раз. Если указывать файл строкой то все норм вроде, а если через переменную то нет..создается но пустой...

Comment: Значит файл в момент записи не закрыт / используется.

Comment: Там в процедуре сначала копируется файл шаблон и потом в новый файл идет вставка - вот тут описал все..Не могу понять почему так. Копия создается а вставка нет..
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946277/excel-send-mail-in-stored-procedure

Comment: Или это нереально сделать ?